# How to create a ADO work item setting the iteration path to current iteration in REST API?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

How to create a ADO work item setting the iteration path to current iteration using REST API?

I try using `@CurrentIteration` as the iteration path of the work item that I create, but I get this error:

```
{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF401347: Invalid tree name given for work item -1, field 'System.IterationPath'.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.WorkItemFieldInvalidTreeNameException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","typeKey":"WorkItemFieldInvalidTreeNameException","errorCode":600171,"eventId":3200}
```

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If the answer helped or gave a right direction, please mark it which will also help others in the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass the `@CurrentIteration` macro in the `System.IterationPath` when you create a workitem, the reason being that the value of current iteration is team specific, but the workitem is created on project level.

What you need to to is to fetch the name of the current iteration for the specific team you have in mind and then pass the iteration path of that.

The current iteration of a team can be fetched via the following  `GET` Request (Please note that `$timeframe` is specified as `Current`)

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations?$timeframe=Current&api-version=6.0
```

For details, please see the REST API documentation for [Iteration - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/iterations/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#timeframe)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I try this work, it works for the first time, it gives me the right values for the current sprint. But when I move to the next sprint (2 weeks later), the API still returns me the old sprint value. Do you have any idea why?